# What is modem MAC MTA address?

Tags: hardware, modem

I've read about some modems having a MAC MTA address. Could you tell me what is a MAC MTA address? What is it used for and what kind of modems usually have it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modem with an [MTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_terminal_adapter) MAC is going to be a cable/VoIP modem. It will have HFC which is the main cable mac and then the MTA MAC which identifies the telephone portion.

Comment: Does the same apply for ADSL modems as well?

What if the cable modem has two VoIP ports; will it have two MAC MTAs?

Comment: @Dario, same for DSL modems; I've never seen one with multiple MACs for the phone, though I suppose it would technically be possible. It's common to see models with multiple phone lines and a single MTA MAC.